# How to represent generic types in assembly language

Tags: generics, assembly, linked-list, mips

I want to implement a generic linked list in assembler. My question is, how do i represent the element of type T? like a pointer?. The TAD list is:

```
Record Node
    element: T
    next   : Node
end

Record Head
    first : Node
    size  : Int
end
```

I wonder how to do this mostly for the reservation of memory for the record Node.

I'm programming in MIPS. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure assembly is the language for doing... any data structure work?

Comment: Google stuff for your assignemts eh .. http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-34/ass34_11.html

Comment: You could maybe cobble together some macros that would generate code based on the element width but this sounds like an exercise in pain. Even working with a fixed width will likely be a chore if you want to actually implement a linked list instead of just doing some assignment-level predefined manipulations. (And macros aren't an assembly language feature as much as a feature of the specific assembler you're using.)

Comment: I know is stupid to program that in assembly but it is just and exercise. I'm thinking of let the element field like a pointer, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assembler, variables and fields don't have types, but only *sizes*. For the most common case of flat 32-bit memory model, the pointers are **four bytes** in size, same as most integers. So you just need to treat them as integers which happen to contain addresses and not just arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking. Thank you